How to put spaces between the digits in an address string with groovy
I receive a string of an address and I need the digits in the string to be separated by a space. This should be able to handle all types of address formats as outlined here.
"1234 South St City, NY 12345" -> "1 2 3 4 South St City, NY 1 2 3 4 5"
I tried a variety of combinations in the replaceAll method but none gave my ideal result.
Attempt 1 : Worked best, but I don't want a space between the "1" & "st" in addresses like this:
123 1st St NW Hampton, IA 12345
def address = "1234 South St City, NY 12345"
address = address.replaceAll(/(\d)/, '$1 ');
address = address.trim();
println(address);

Attempt 2:
def address = "1234 South St City, NY 12345"
address = address.replaceAll(/\d{3,}/, '$0 ');
address = address.trim();
println(address);

Attempt 3:
def address = "1234 South St City, NY 12345"
address = address.replaceAll(/(\d{3,})/, '$1 ');
address = address.trim();
println(address);

Attempt 4
def address = "1234 South St City, NY 12345"
address = address.replaceAll(/\d{3,5}/, '$0 ');
address = address.trim();
println(address);


try: address.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d)", "$0 ");

This sounds like an XY Problem. What use is it to separate digits with spaces?

Thank you for the idea, this is the solution:
address.replaceAll(/\d(?=\d)/,'$0 ')

